# how to do the c# like syntax where you dont need curly braces for just one line of code?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

in c#, this is valid code
`if(expression) doSomething();` so you don't have to write `if(expression) { doSomething();}` how do i express such grammar rule in antlr4?

maybe writing `block: ('{' line* '}')|(line)` is the way to go? please do not answer "just try and see if it works", thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is one way to do it.

This is how it is written in the [C# grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/csharp/CSharpParser.g4) in the ANTLR repo:

```
simple_embedded_statement
    : ';'
    | expression ';'
    | IF OPEN_PARENS expression CLOSE_PARENS if_body (ELSE if_body)?
    | ...
    ;

if_body
    : block
    | simple_embedded_statement
    ;

block
    : OPEN_BRACE statement_list? CLOSE_BRACE
    ;
```